# Installing Visual Studio 2008 TS after Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I recently installed Visual Studio Professional 2010 Beta 1 and noticed that most of the install directories were independent of "shared" directories (I have Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express installed and didn't notice any conflicts).  If I install the full version (non-beta/trialware), of VS 2008 TS, will it conflict at all with the VS 2010 Beta 1 install ?  I probably should have installed VS 2008 TS first...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the reverse would probably be the better choice, I've done exactly as you've described and have not run into problems on that machine yet.  Both installations seem to run fine independent of each other.

Comment: Ah, great news mikestew!  Thanks for letting me know.