# Installing vs2008 over vs2010

Tags: visual-studio, bitset

Because of bitset problem in vs2010, i will also install vs2008 which doesn't have that bug. But as i remember, in my old experiences, there were a few conflicts in windows sdk. I don't exactly remember but how can i fix these conflicts ? Or is there any conflict ?

Comment: I have 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed and AFAIK there are no conflicts (note I don't use the IDE though).

Comment: What conflicts are you referring to? I run 2005, 2008 and 2010 without issue.

Comment: Are you actually trying to have VS2008 *overwrite* code in VS2010? Because that's not going to work. You can have them all installed side-by-side, but you can't have 2010's compiler with 2008's standard library.

Comment: Little or large, there are bugs both in VS 2010 and VS 2008 and always will be in any future versions. It's hard to believe that std::bitset is critical to your application, but in any case it's not worth VS downgrading. Don't let software bugs lead your way. And btw, there are workarounds, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947322/bitsets-in-c-using-vs2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you might be referring to would be the Windows SDK config tool shipped with Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 had a serious bug in that it would fail to properly set the SDK version in the registry.

You can read about the issue here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/03/01/integrating-windows-sdk-and-vs-with-new-sdk-configuration-tool.aspx

As mentioned in the post there are various solutions to ensure that you're building against the correct SDK version.

I personally have Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 RC1 installed with no issues thus far.

One minor gripe I had when I installed Visual Studio 2008 on top of 2010 was that it changed all of my file associations to point to 2008 instead of 2010.  To fix this, you can open 2010 and go to Tools->Settings->Environment->General and press "Restore File Associations".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have MSVC6, 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed side by side on Win7 x64 and have no problems at all. All of them work with GUI (IDEs), debugger, etc. However, I use only C/C++, so experience with other languages may be different.

Also see replies to the same or similar questions:

- [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)
- [Installing Visual Studio 2008 TS after Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448937/installing-visual-studio-2008-ts-after-visual-studio-2010-beta-1)
- [Install Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 beside VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609235/install-visual-studio-2010-beta-2-beside-vs2008)